# Archivos Binarios en lenguaje C

Tags: c

Tengo una duda de cómo almacenar en una variable de tipo `char` un nombre de entre varios guardados en un archivo binario en lenguaje C, ademas que el nombre es seleccionado de forma aleatoria,  para luego mostrar el nombre guardado por medio de la variable

este es el codigo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){

    int cont=0,num;

    srand(time(NULL));
    char aux[50];

    FILE *archivo;
    num=rand()%51;
    archivo=fopen("doc.dat","rb");

    if(archivo==NULL){
        printf("Error de apertura");
    }

    while(!feof(archivo)){
        cont++;
        if(cont==num){
            fgets(aux,50,archivo);
        }
    }
    fclose(archivo);

    printf("%s",aux);
}
```

y  el archivo binario tiene guardado lo siguiente:

```
Son GokuVegetaSon GohanSon GotenTrunksKrilinFreezerYamchaTen Shin HanGoku BlackBob EsponjaCalamardoDon CangrejoPatricio EstrellaYugi MutoAangZukoETAlfDanny PhantomBruce WayneDick GraysonJason ToddTim DrakeDrake ParkerJosh NicholsClark KentCrash BandicootSonic El ErizoShadow El ErizoJason VoorheesPamela VoorheesFreddy KruegerHomero J SimpsonBart SimpsonLisa SimpsonMoe SzyslakBarney GomezDraculaVictor FrankensteinHombre LoboHarry PotterMarioLuigiPrincesa PeachToadBowserLinkPrincesa ZeldaGanondorf
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo revisar [ask] y el [tour], de esta forma ganarás una de tus primeras medallas. En futuras ocasiones, por favor, elimina los espacios en blanco innecesarios... si el código acaba teniendo scroll que sea debido a su extensión y no a la existencia de decenas de líneas en blanco.

Answer (score 1):

Tu intención es leer el fichero palabra a palabra... para ello puedes usar `fscanf`, que funciona exactamente igual que `scanf` pero sobre ficheros.

Por otro lado, tu bucle de lectura está mal ya que, si te fijas, solo realizará una lectura cuando `cont==num`... el resto del tiempo no va a mover el apuntador del fichero, luego **siempre** va a leer los primeros 50 caracteres del mismo.

Quedarte con la palabra número `num` es tan sencillo como crear un bucle que itere en el rango `(0,num)` y, en cada iteración, lea una palabra del fichero... cuando el programa abandone el bucle tendrás en `aux` la palabra buscada.

Admás, ten en cuenta que desde C99 (que data de 1999... hace ya 19 años) es posible declarar las variables en cualquier parte del código:

```
for( int cont=0; !feof(archivo) && cont != num; ++cont )
{
  fscanf(archivo,"%s",aux);
}
```

Comment: si, basicamente lo que quiero es que me mueva el fichero y el numero aleatorio sea igual a la posicion de linea de la alguna palabra del fichero y esa tomarla para una variable , estoy haciendo un ahorcado como proyecto final pero debe incluir binarios y me cuesta algo de trabajo acabar de entenderlo